# Exim routing based on individual email addresses

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, migration, exim

I am trying to migrate individual users, one at a time, from an Exim based mail system to an Exchange 2010 system.  I'm hoping to do this by leaving the Exim based system as the MX for the time being, and as a user mailbox is created on the Exchange system, then a manualroute rule is created for that user on the exim system, so that any mail addressed to them from both local and remote senders is delivered to the Exchange mailbox instead.

My experience with Exim is limited, but it appears that the manual routing rules I've seen thus far are domain based, but these addresses (on the Exchange and Exim systems) will have the same domains, so I'm hoping that I can route based on specific email addresses.  What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Exim Book gives an example of manualroute with user part lookups [5.6.1 Using a manualroute router](http://books.google.pl/books?id=foCRVaMeRMgC&pg=PA85)

Below please find it modified to your needs (based on [7.4 The manualroute router](http://books.google.pl/books?id=foCRVaMeRMgC&pg=PA127) in the book):

```
exchange_people:
   driver = manualroute
   domains = example.net  ## limit router to addresses in example.net domain
   local_parts = lsearch;/etc/e_users 
   route_list = * exchange.example.net ## send to  exchange.example.net host
   transport = remote_smtp
```